# Is there a way to get all apps from a developer on Google Play

Tags: android, json, xml, google-play

I want to display a list all apps from a specific developer in a Android app.

Is there a way to search Google Play and get a xml or Json response with all apps from the specified developer? (with info like icon url, title and description)

I know I can link to a page with all apps from a developer inside Google Play, but I want to display the apps inside the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official API for such things, but "You can create a Custom Search Engine that only looks at the Play Store, and use the Custom Search Engine API to search the play store." Check the second answer here: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-API-for-the-Google-Play-Store

The first answer there also offers two external solutions, https://github.com/chadrem/market_bot and https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/.